# I can't find database connection in python tkinter gui

Tags: python, database, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I have just started database in python. I am making a tkinter gui that can keep information of the users in simple database sqlite3. I am having problem with the picture I show. Help me please. If you confused with it. Ask for a code, I will provide. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your database doesn't have any table named records,  first try to make a table then insert data.

Comment: Thank you all. solved

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example which may help you

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
root=Tk()
name= StringVar()# variables 
phone=StringVar()
def save():
    c= sqlite3.connect('gun.db')# database connection
    cr=c.cursor()# creating cursor object
    cr.execute('create table if not exist save(Name TEXT,Phone TEXT)')# creating table
    cr.execute( "insert into save values ('%s','%s')"%(name.get(),phone.get()))# inserting value in the table
    c.commit()# saving data in database
    cr.close()#closing the cursor
    
label1=Label(root,text='Name').grid(row=0,column=0)
entry1=Entry(root,textvar=name,font=('arial 12 bold')).grid(row=0,column=1)
label2=Label(root,text='phone no').grid(row=1,column=0)
entry2=Entry(root,textvar=phone,font=('arial 12 bold')).grid(row=1,column=1)
btn=Button(root,text='save',command=save).grid(row=2,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`.